# Issues with downloading Parallel pages Asynchronously with puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

It does not seem that, there is parallel download happening when I am downloading a batch of urls. The url downloading is completing way late than it does when downloaded individually.

I am using a 2 core ec2-machine with 4gb RAM. All system resources(cpu, ram, network) are pretty stable in a batch size of 30 urls. The connection time out used here is 30 seconds. Their are urls which complete as late as 15 s, 20 secs, 23 secs which complete in about 3-6 seconds when run individually. Is not parallel IO supposed to happen here. What am I missing?

```
let startDate new Date();
let finishDate;
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

await puppeteer.launch().then(async browser => {
  const promises=[];
  urlArr.forEach(function(url){
  promises.push(browser.newPage().then(async page => {
          try{
              await page.goto(url.startsWith('http') ? url :     
              `http://${url}`, {
                    waitUntil: ['load'],timeout:connectionTimeOut
              });

              const html = await page.content();
              finishDate = new Date();
              console.log("html download complete for " + url + " - " +     
              finishDate.getTime() + " - " + (finishDate.getTime() - 
              startDate.getTime())/1000);

            }catch(err){
              console.log(err)
            }
       }))
  });
  await Promise.all(promises)
  await browser.close();
})
```

Comment: Can you give us your `urlArr`?

Comment: urlArr here could be list of any n domains. For example ["google.com", "yahoo.com", "stackoverflow.com", "github.com"]

Comment: If you run a big number of tests it's normal that they slow down since your network bandwidth and cpu power is limited. I think the solution for you should be running, for example, max 3 tests at once in parallel. This library should be helpful:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-promise-pool

Comment: I don't think this will work. All resource including CPU, RAM, Network are stable. The instance type which I am using has a network bandwidth of 2000 MBPS.  Have done the same exercise with batch size of 5 as well.
Getting the same results, so network does not seem to be the culprit here. Although will give this library a shot and verify.

What is observed here is that all 'goto' operations for all urls get started simultaneously but its completion and 'download' operation occur sequentially. There is some blocking operation happening which is resulting in this sequential competition.